# Export arcgis data to xml all at once

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, export, xml

Is there a way in ArcGIS10 to export all feat classes, tables, datasets all at once as XML?  I know there is a batch command but still appears you have to select items.
I am in process of writing a script but do not yet know what method/function in ArcGIS to use that would get all at once the FeatureClassList, TableList, and DatasetList instead of getting one by one and then manipulating.

Any Help is appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, in ArcGIS 10.0 you can export schema or data to an XML file manually if you right click on your geodatabase > Export > XML Workspace Document.  You can also do this using [ArcObjects](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_export_a_dataset_to_XML/000100000099000000/).

You can do the same in ArcGIS 10.1 but there also exists an [Export XML Workspace Document (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000015s000000) geoprocessing tool to accomplish this that you can leverage in your python scripting that was [newly added at 10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Data_Management_toolbox/016w0000004n000000/).

Therefore, if you are using python to script, I am not sure you have access to methods/functions for easily exporting to XML at 10.0.